# curl command ssl not working gives LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: curl, amazon-elb

My curl command to AWS ALB is not working

```
    curl -v --cacert "/filepath/cert.pem" --cert "filepath/cert.pem:password" \
https://xxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/xxxx/xxxx \
-H "Accept:application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Host:myhost.com"
```

Gives the below error:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /filepath/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to xxx.xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to xxx.xxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443
```

I also did `echo | openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443`

And openssl returns Verify return code: 0 (ok)

I also verified that the domain name on my cert matches with the accepted domain name in the alb listener. Any idea as what is wrong with my request?

Note: I also tried without --cacert option and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your ALB subnets have route tables that contain a route to the internet via an internet gateway. If they do not you will see the connection hang as shown in your question.

I have just spent many hours tracking down this same problem and these missing routes turned out to be the cause. The AWS Console warns you, however doesn't block you.